# Mute Role Saves To The Muted User When They Leave

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

**Hi, I've been working on "Saving / giving the mute role to the muted user who left the server" for quite awhile now. I even tried using quick.db, but it didnt worked**

Is there anything I can do to make this? I would appriciate your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Creating persistent roles for users is only accomplished by using databases. You must keep record of everytime a persistent role is added to the member, and have bot check for the member and their persistent roles every time they join back.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store your users in a JSON database with lowdb.

Example of your bot code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')

const adapter = new FileSync('db.json')
const db = low(adapter)

client.once('ready', () => {
    db.defaults({users: [] })
    .write()

    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    //when you mute a user add you multiple actions and:
    db.get('users')
  .push({ user: userID, muted: 'yes'})
  .write()
    

});
```

You will have to create a db.json file beforehand of course.